# How to #let a JSON file in RSpec on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec, let

**EDIT:**

The solution seems to start with `describe KayNein::Twitter do` instead of `RSpec.describe KayNein::Twitter do`.

Why is this the case?

Rails 5.2.1
Ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

**Original Question**

I have a class that initializes with a JSON file:

```
module KayNein
  class Twitter < Handler

    def initialize(json_file)
      @website_hash = JSON.parse(json_file)
    end
```

And I'm trying to write an RSpec:

```
RSpec.describe KayNein::Twitter do
  let (:json_file) {File.read(PATH_TO_FILE)}
  context "Initialized" do
    subject = KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file)
  end
end
```

But RSpec gives me this error:

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/app/kay_nein/sites/twitter_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: subject = KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file)
  `json_file` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run
 in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).
# ./spec/app/kay_nein/sites/twitter_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/app/kay_nein/sites/twitter_spec.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/app/kay_nein/sites/twitter_spec.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Even this gives me an error, so it has nothing to do with the file:

```
RSpec.describe KayNein::Twitter do
  let (:json_file) {"Hello world"}
  context "Initialized" do
    subject = KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file)
  end
end
```

Comment: have you defined: ` {File.read(PATH_TO_FILE)}`?

Comment: also, does File.read return a value? I couldn't find it the documentation.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes it is defined, I'm just not disclosing the file path here for the sake of privacy

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes, File.read returns a value, it reads it as a JSON file.

Comment: are you pasting in the full file? is your test wrapped in a `it "returns a file" do   {write your test here}   end`?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon yes, that's the full file.

Comment: well then you need a test. write an `it` statement followed with a test.

Answer (score 1):

```
We have two ways to DRY up tests (before and let) that share an intersecting purpose, to create variables that are common across tests. For common variable instantiation, the Ruby community prefers let, and while before is often used to perform actions common across tests.

when you use the context you can initialize the let inside the context block like this, will work

describe KayNein::Twitter do
  context "Initialized" do
    let (:json_file) {File.read(PATH_TO_FILE)}
    subject = KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file)
  end
end

otherwise if you don't want to use context, can try this way

describe KayNein::Twitter do
let (:json_file) {File.read(PATH_TO_FILE)}
  it "Initialized" do
    subject = KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this ?

```
let(:file) { File.read(File.join('spec', 'fixtures', 'public', filename)) }

describe "File" do
  it "should be a file" do
    expect(file).to be_a File
  end

  it "should initialize and read the contents"
    initialize_file = KayNein::Twitter.new(file)
    expect(response.body["key"]).to eq(..)
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this inadvertantly helped me solve it.  I removed "RSpec" from `Rspec.describe` and now I can #let.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `let` as defining accessors. And those accessors are available only inside example blocks `it` or `specify`.

You are trying to use `json_file` (defined in let) inside a `context`. And this is exactly what the error message is trying to tell you:

> `json_file` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or
>   `context` block). It is only available from within individual examples
>   (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run  in the scope of an
>   example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc).

You can fix it like this:

```
RSpec.describe KayNein::Twitter do
  let (:json_file) {File.read(PATH_TO_FILE)}
  context "Initialized" do
    specify do # it instead of specify also works
     subject = KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file)
     expect(subject).not_to be_nil # this is just an example, not needed to 
                                   # get rid of the issue
    end
  end
end
```

or even better - define subject outside of example block (for reusability etc) like this:

```
RSpec.describe KayNein::Twitter do
  let (:json_file) {File.read(PATH_TO_FILE)}
  subject { KayNein::Twitter.new(json_file) }
  context "Initialized" do
    specify do # it instead of specify also works
     expect(subject).not_to be_nil # this is just an example, not needed to 
                                   # get rid of the issue
    end
  end
end
```